# HQL changing year/month/date into year-month-date

Tags: date, hql

I have tried with DATE_FORMAT(original_date,'%Y-%m-%d'), and it's not working. Anyone know the answer quick? Searching google hasn't really been helpful.

Answer (score 0):

from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('2015/01/01' ,'yyyy/MM/dd'), 'yyyy-MM-dd')

That works!